# With pybind11, how to split my code into multiple modules/files?

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

With pybind11, how to split my code into multiple modules/files?
This would speed up the compilation step.
Pybind11 documentation addresses the special case of extending a type declared in a different extension module, [here](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/misc.html#partitioning-code-over-multiple-extension-modules). But not the more general/simpler one.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As per pybind11 FAQ, [here](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#how-can-i-reduce-the-build-time), `PYBIND11_MODULE(module_name, m){ /* bindings */ }` can be split in multiple functions defined in different files. Example:

example.cpp:

```
void init_ex1(py::module &);
void init_ex2(py::module &);
/* ... */

PYBIND11_MODULE(example, m) {
    init_ex1(m);
    init_ex2(m);
    /* ... */
}
```

ex1.cpp:

```
void init_ex1(py::module &m) {
    m.def("add", [](int a, int b) { return a + b; });
}
```

ex2.cpp:

```
void init_ex2(py::module &m) {
    m.def("sub", [](int a, int b) { return a - b; });
}
```

Comment: What about the `PYBIND11_MODULE` statement? Can you have multiple `PYBIND11_MODULE` that append to the current module?

Comment: @Mikhail no, there should only be one, you can share the module object. As any lib that you compile.